# escaped whitespaces in paths osx/unix/darwin, plain C

Tags: c, macos, unix, darwin

Here's a simple file path plain-C routine which should programmatically expand tildes and accept whitespaces as legitimate characters in file names. It works fine with names such as:

~/Test Folder/test.txt

/Users/Shared/Test Folder/test.txt

but does not seem to work with path syntax as suggested by Apple or as generated by Terminal.app if drag&dropping file's icon to the Terminal.app's window:

/Users/Shared/Test\ Folder/test.txt

or

~/Test\ Folder/test.txt

Here's the code. I'm obviously missing the routine which would substitute 'escaped whitespace' for 'plain whitespace' characters. On the other hand, any search routine for '\ ' results in compiler complaints about "unknown escape sequence" 0x20 (which btw. seems to be the valid whitespace code in some unix and linux systems, possibly not in OSX?).

Is there a solution to the problem within plain-C and C-strings, without having to deal with Apple's proprietary CFStrings and NSStrings, where I know that solutions are simple? I just can't afford using any of those in this program. Also no shell scripts, ruby, gawk, grep, perl, python, etc..., please.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wordexp.h>

void get_file_path(char path[])
{
    char *p;
    size_t len = 0;
    wordexp_t exp_result;

    printf("Enter file name: \n");    
    p = fgets(path, TEXT_SIZE, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    if(p != NULL)len = strlen(path);

    //get rid of newline characters
    for(p = path; p < path + len; p++){
        if(*p == '\n') *p = '\0';
    }

    if(path[0] == '~'){
        wordexp(path, &exp_result, 0);
        //printf("Num.expansions: %zd\n", exp_result.we_wordc);
        strcpy(path, exp_result.we_wordv[0]);        

        for(size_t i = 1; i < exp_result.we_wordc; i++){
        //printf("%s\n", exp_result.we_wordv[i]);
        strcat(path, " ");
        strcat(path, exp_result.we_wordv[i]);
        }
    wordfree(&exp_result);        
    }
    printf("File path: %s\n", path);
    return;
}
```

Here's the shell output:

```
Enter file name: 
/Users/Shared/Test\ Folder/test.txt
File path: /Users/Shared/Test\ Folder/test.txt
Can't open file: /Users/Shared/Test\ Folder/test.txt
```

Comment: You don't need to replace `"\ "` with `" "` because that will be done by the shell AFAIK.

Comment: If so, either mentioned path syntax would work. But since it doesn't, it seemingly **isn't** done by the shell, for a reason or not. Please feel free to try it yourself. I've posted the code.

Comment: I don't own a Mac so it might behave diferently.

Comment: Macs use bash as the default shell.  It works the same there as on Linux.

Comment: Have you tested this example - I know it should work on Linux? Yet, I'm a bit afraid that discussing theoretically about bash being the default shell which **should** work all the same on either system seems a bit off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to the main issue with code, but it is a problem with the code.

`if(path[0] == '~'){` is a subtle problem.

```
p = fgets(path, TEXT_SIZE, stdin);
...
if(path[0] == '~'){
```

When `p == NULL` the content of `path` is not define on IO error and likely the previous buffer contents when `EOF` occurs.  Better to change return type from `void` to `char *`,  and return when `p == NULL`.

```
p = fgets(path, TEXT_SIZE, stdin);
if (p == NULL) { 
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: thanks, for pointing me at this subtle problem. I revised the code following your suggestion, and accepted the answer for being most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

iharob is right that the shell will translate unquoted or double-quoted ("...") appearances of `"\ "` to a single space character.  The resulting space does not split words.  On the other hand, that only happens when you present such a string to the shell in the first place.  It does not happen if you bypass the shell, such when you launch a process directly via the `exec()` family of functions, or when the string is otherwise used only internally in a program.

You seem to be having a bit of trouble distinguishing shell syntax from C syntax.  The shell interprets the backslash character as a *general purpose* escape character, but C recognizes only specific escape sequences (all introduced by a backslash) and `'\ '` is not one of them.

On the other hand, `'\\'` *is* one of them: it represents a single backslash character.  Thus, if you are looking for a string literal for a two-character string whose elements are a backslash followed by a space, then in C that's spelled `"\\ "`.

**UPDATE:**

All that aside, I think your real problem is that your program performs expansion only if the first character of the string is a `~`.  That is not the case in the test run you presented.  Your code (more or less) works for me in that case if the expansion is performed unconditionally.

Comment: Also note that you need to escape a literal backslash to present it to the shell, too.  The path syntax generated by dropping a file onto `Terminal.app` is intended for consumption by the shell, which is absolutely appropriate for that context.

Comment: Thanks - You're probably right. This path argument has nothing to do with the shell, therefore I had insisted in plain C, I don't have a problem with distinguishing C from bash. I'm only aware that people who use my program drag-drop file icons to the terminal window because they're getting frustrated with typos from copying long and complicated file paths - and complain about this issue. All I do is trying to find a way of helping them. I'll give it a try following your advice, and let the community know how it worked.

Comment: @user3078414, I have updated my answer with an explanation of why the code you presented does not perform the expansion you expected.  Again, none of this has anything to do with differences between OS X and Linux.

Comment: Yes, you're right about about the first tilde character limitation, aside of what you may think I may expect. This limitation is there for a purpose. Thanks, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

This slightly revised code seems to do the job. It's a very simple solution which copies all characters except for literal backslashes ( \ ) to an auxiliary character array and adjusts this array's length before searching for tildes (~) at the beginning of the array and expanding the path in case a tilde is found there. Thanks for the discussion, explanations, suggestions and comments!

```
bool get_file_path(char path[]){
char *p, *p1;
char path1[TEXT_SIZE];
size_t len = 0;
size_t len1, i;
wordexp_t exp_result;

printf("Enter file name: \n"); 
fix:
p = fgets(path, TEXT_SIZE, stdin); 
if(p == NULL) return false;   
else{
len = strlen(path);
if(strcmp(path,"\n") == 0)goto fix;
}
//get rid of "escaped whitespaces"
for(p = path, p1 = path1, len1 = len; p < path + len; p++, p1++){
    if(*p == '\\'){p++; len1--;}
    *p1 = *p;
}        
//get rid of newline characters
for(p1 = path1; p1 < path1 + len1; p1++){
    if(*p1 == '\n') *p1 = '\0';
}    
if(path1[0] == '~'){
    wordexp(path1, &exp_result, 0);
    //printf("Num.expansions: %zd\n", exp_result.we_wordc);
    strcpy(path1, exp_result.we_wordv[0]);        
    for(i = 1; i <  exp_result.we_wordc; i++){
    //printf("%s\n", exp_result.we_wordv[i]);
    strcat(path1, " ");
    strcat(path1, exp_result.we_wordv[i]);
    }
wordfree(&exp_result);        
}
strcpy(path, path1);    
printf("File path: %s\n", path);
return true;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Since *fflush(stdin)* generates undefined behavior except for Linux, three extra lines of code can help getting rid of "stray newlines" in the *stdin* buffer instead of relying on *fflush()* to do it.